# redisson / jvm serialization issue

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, redisson

We started to observe some weird behaviour in a spring boot application that is using redisson.

There is a redisson map, where entities are being added and read.
In some cases after reading an entity from the map it is deserialized incorrectly - it contains a **wrong type** in a field.

The given field (**sourceDescription**) is actually defined as string but we are seeing an UUID in there. Attaching a screenshot from the debugger.:

[image]

The field in the Alarm object is a String:

```
@JsonAlias({"sourceDescription", "source_description"})
private String sourceDescription;
```

Reading from the map is a one-liner:

```
final RMap<UUID, List<Alarm>> map = redisson.getMap(ALARM_QUEUE);
```

Adding is straigt forward as well

```
final List<Alarm> queuedAlarms = new ArrayList<>(map.get(key));
queuedAlarms.add(alarm);
map.put(key, queuedAlarms);
```

How is that even possible that the JVM allows a **wrong type** in a field?

Comment: can you give try this for normal Hashmap and confirm if the behaviour is same ?